# Note question: Stravinsky Suite Italienne (Cello)

Tags: cello

Anyone familiar with Stravinsky' s Suite Italienne?  I've got a question on a odd-sounding note.  See the first circled chord in the pic -- the fingering doesn't make sense, and the note doesn't match the E doesn't match the D in the second circled chord, tho' the piano part is the same in both places.  This is from the Boosey&Hawkes edition.

[image: Suite Italienne, Minuetto]

Comment: Have you checked any other editions of the score? Also, have you reached out to any cellist friends?

Comment: @jjmusicnotes I'm in the process of doing just that.

Comment: Don't know the piece well enough to actually answer, but you're right, that fingering makes no sense if it's actually E and C. That would break your hand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had a listen to a couple of recordings and both have E & C where your first circle is and D & C for the second circle. I don't have a copy to compare but I would go with it and assume it's a deliberate dissonance.

I agree the thumb/third finger combination is a bit odd and cramped (why not use just 1 and 2 as in the previous bar?) but I guess the rationale is that you are well-positioned to play the semiquavers which follow, especially if you're taking this at a brisk tempo.  However both recordings I listened to were pretty relaxed in tempo!